# $L=\left\{awb\mid a,b\in \Sigma \wedge a<b \wedge w \in \Sigma^*\right\}$ find NFA that accepts L

Tags: automata, regular-language

Given the alphabet $\Sigma = \left\{ 1,2,3,4 \right\}$, I have to find a NFA that accepts the language:
$$L=\left\{awb\mid a,b\in \Sigma \wedge a<b \wedge w \in \Sigma^*\right\}$$.

I don't know how build a general NFA for all case. Indeed I thought to do a NFA for every case and then joining all the costructions but I don't think is the better way...
Can somebody help me?

Comment: I could figure out an NFA that has $7$ states with $3$ final states. Maybe this is the same NFA that you had thought?

Comment: @PJK Nope... I figured out a NFA with 4 states but I already know that mine is wrong

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Label the arrows as below:

$q_0\rightarrow q_1$ as $1$

$q_0\rightarrow q_2$ as $1, 2$

$q_0\rightarrow q_3$ as $1, 2, 3$

$q_1\rightarrow q_4$ as $2$

$q_2\rightarrow q_5$ as $3$

$q_3\rightarrow q_6$ as $4$

and $q_1, q_2, q_3$ have self loops labelled $1, 2, 3, 4$.